# QtCreator semantic issue warning code will never be executed

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I have following chunk of `Qt` code:

```
if(this->ueCommunicationsSocket()->bind(QHostAddress(data[0].toString()),
                                        static_cast<quint16>(data[1].toInt())),
                                        QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << "TCP socket bind succesfull";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << QString::number(this->ueCommunicationsSocket()->error())
             << this->ueCommunicationsSocket()->errorString();  // here i get semantic issue
}   // if
```

and I am getting **semantic issue warning code will never be executed**. I am aware this is some dumb mistake and I am ready to get downvote(s), however, I cannot find mistake! Here is also a screenshot:
[image: Qt Creator Semantic Issue]

Comment: What compiler are you using? Is it clang?

Comment: Nope, it's `gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.1)`

Comment: @KernelPanic are you compiling in release or with QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT defined? It doesn't look like so as the other QDebug doesn't seem to be warning but I'm asking because I bumped into this recently: http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-December/020171.html

Comment: @Uflex no, at the moment I compile/build in debug mode with `QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT` **NOT** defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(this->ueCommunicationsSocket()->bind(QHostAddress(data[0].toString()),
                                        static_cast<quint16>(data[1].toInt())),
                                        QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress)
```

is

```
if ( /*something */, QAbstractSocket::ShareAddress)
```

since `AbstractSocket::SharedAddress` is `0x1`, this condition with a comma operator `!` **is always true**, i.e. the `else` branch will never be executed.