# Qt 5.14.2 gets semantic issues when inserting elements to std::map

Tags: c++, qt, dictionary

I am using Qt 5.14.2(MSVC2017 compiler) in win10 system. When I insert data with std::map, there is a compilation error.

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <map>

#include <utility>

#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    
    std::map<int, int> mymap;
    auto a = std::make_pair(5,6); //no error message

    //semantic issue: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair(1,2));

    //semantic issue: no matching member function for call to 'insert'
    mymap.insert(a);

    mymap.insert({3, 4}); //no error message

    return app.exec();

}
```

In addition, I used to compile with Qt 5.4.2(MSVC2012 compiler) with no problems.

——————————————————————————————————————————

I made a mistake, it is a semantic issue marked by the red circle, not an error, and it doesn't affect the results of the program. Previous Qt 5.4.2 version I used before does not have this semantic issue.

Problems related to Qt semantic issue:

[Semantic Issue Qt Creator: no member named 'cout' in namespace 'std'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63942414/semantic-issue-qt-creator-no-member-named-cout-in-namespace-std)

[QtCreator semantic issue warning code will never be executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605753/qtcreator-semantic-issue-warning-code-will-never-be-executed)

[error use of undeclared identifier 'mainwindow' semantic issue in QtCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65979436/error-use-of-undeclared-identifier-mainwindow-semantic-issue-in-qtcreator)

Comment: Why is this related to Qt?

Comment: Because I'm developing in Qt.

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/9KTSKiFq0     This code compile and seems to work. I believe some issue with MSVC2017? or maybe you posted partial code, without the actual problem?

Comment: Works with MSVC 2019 i.e. 14.29.30037
Your compiler is just to old.

Comment: @Adrian Maire I used to use Qt 5.4.2(MSVC2012) and it works, but recently I need to upgrade to Qt 5.14.2(MSVC2017), the previous code compile error. The above code and errors are that run in Qt 5.14.2(MSVC2017).

Comment: @Superlokkus  Which version of Qt are you using?

Comment: None.  Your code is not related to Qt. At least the code you show us. The qt creater might use wrong flags for the MSVC compiler you are actually using. But you are not posting that project settings either, and that would be a total other and duplicate problem

Comment: See also the answer update

Comment: Don't change the code of your question, your code was closer to an [mre] than now. And still your problem has nothing to do with Qt. You have a [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @ Superlokkus : I updated the code with full qt code.

Comment: @cd-00 Please revert to the old version, because the things you add are not relevant and its against stack overflow good pratice to move away from a [mre] . The MSVC version 2013 you said is as I said not capable. If you have a newer MSVC version and it still doesnt work you question becomes a "How do I tell Qt creator to not misconfigure MSVC"

Comment: @Superlokkus: The code works without on web (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/?kw=make_pair), but gets error on Qt 5.14.2(MSVC2017). So I emphasize the qt version.

Comment: That doesnt make sense. Now your question is incomplete because the `mainwindow.h` is missing, and you should try the code you first posted on that "qt version". Also your error is not related to the code part, either you project is misconfigured or you have an error in the parts now shown. As I said either you have an XY problem because of Qt induced MSVC misconfiguration or the wrong MSVC version. You did not give the 2017 MSVC Version number and as I said, a specific Minor version of 2017 is required or you even did something completly else wrong, which we can not reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value );` of `std::map`. That overload is introduced by C++17. Your compiler is too old for that, it is not compliant with C++17. It seems the minimal version you have to upgrade to is MSVC 19.0 (Update 2)* i.e. VS 2015. Better upgrade to full C++17 or even later version by upgrading to MSVC 2019. VS 2015-2019 are compatible in many ways anyway, like the ABI. In general its always good practice to use the up to date tools and libraries. Also your question is not related to Qt in any way.

I have tested it local with VS 2019 and [also with the oldest available on compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:13,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:13,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:13,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:13),source:%27%23include+%3Cutility%3E++++++//+std::pair%0A%23include+%3Cmap%3E%0A%0A%0Aint+main+()+%0A%7B%0A++++std::map%3Cint,+int%3E+mymap%3B%0A++++auto+a1+%3D+std::make_pair(1,2)%3B+//no+error+message%0A++++mymap.insert(std::make_pair(3,4))%3B+//no+matching+function+for+call+to+!%27make_pair!%27%0A++++mymap.insert(a1)%3B+//mo+matching+member+function+for+call+to+!%27insert!%27%0A%0A++++mymap.insert(%7B5,6%7D)%3B+//no+error+message%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:52.41330655505917,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:vcpp_v19_14_x86,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86+msvc+v19.14+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),k:47.58669344494085,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86+msvc+v19.14+(Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:50,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). It works test at least with 14.14 1914 (Visual Studio 2017 version 15.7)

To further elaborate why that missing overload seems to be surprisingly important, I bet that the following code works with your compiler (I cant reproduce):

```
#include <utility>      // std::pair
#include <map>


int main () 
{
    std::map<int, int> mymap;
    auto a1 = std::make_pair<const int, int>(1,2); 
    mymap.insert(std::make_pair<const int,int>(3,4)); 
    mymap.emplace(3,4); 
    mymap.insert(a1); 

    mymap.insert({5,6}); //no error message
}
```

Comment: The above (original) code should work with C++11 IMHO.

Comment: The code works with MSVC2012(Qt 5.4.2), and c++11 compiler(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/make_pair/?kw=make_pair).

Comment: I am quite sure we use `std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value ); and According to CPP Reference  this is a C++17 overload. And according to CPP Reference what seems to be the `std::pair` improvements, it is not implemented by the 2013 version as I mentioned

Comment: @cd-00 I don't see how, you linked the `std::make_pair` function but as I said the relevant part are the overloads of `std::map::insert`

Comment: @Superlokkus：This is the introduction to map::insert(http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/). I run code on the side and choose c++11, it works.

Comment: You are linking a reference, is see no code there which is run. Also cplusplus.com is often wrong, and it is in conflict with what cppreference.com says. I could look up in the std, but I thrust cppreference simply more than cplusplus.com

Comment: I have looked into the standard and as I said there is no `std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value );` but since C++11 there is `pair<iterator, bool> insert(const value_type& x);` However thanks to my IDE I know that  `std::pair<iterator, bool> insert( value_type&& value );` is used, so my original advice to you still holds, since I think the error, which you still posted incomplete, is because `std::make_pair` wants to create a `std::pair<int,int>` but you need a `std::pair<const int, int>`. Without the `&&` overload I guess that difference gets curcial. Stick the t parameter

Comment: @Superlokkus: I made a mistake, it is a semantic issue, not an error, and it doesn't affect the results of the program. Previous Qt 5.4.2 does not have this red circle error.

Comment: Try to add what the mistake was and how this semantic error presented in our question, so others that google/search your problem will be helped.

Comment: @ Superlokkus : I explained the semantic issues in the code comments and changed the title. However, I think this issue should be closed, and I voted to close it.